# How to run command within a prompt set by shell script

Tags: export, environment-variables, ksh, shell-exec

This is the process we perform manually.

```
$ sudo su - gvr
[gvr/DB:DEV3FXCU]/home/gvr>
$ ai_dev.env
Gateway DEV3 $
$ gw_report integrations long
report is ******
```

Now i am attempting to automate this process using a shell script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
sudo su - gvr
. ai_dev3.env
gw_report integrations long
```

but this is not  working. Getting stuck after entering the env.
Stuck at this place (Gateway DEV3 $)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not running the same commands in the two examples - `gw_report long` != `gw_report integrations long`. Maybe the latter takes much longer (or hangs).

Also, in the original code you *run* `ai_dev.env` and in the second you *source* it. Any variables set when running a script are *gone* when returning from that script, so I suspect this accounts for the different behavior.

Comment: Hi I0b0. sorry my intention is to run `gw_report integrations long`
 in both the cases. Problem is, when i run the script it simply switches user, then changes env variables and then it waits for input.
Unlike i am expecting it to read this `gw_report integrations long` and execute.